# Convert Weeknumber to date using Python and Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, date, week-number

I need help extracting the weekdate from my df:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'weeknum':[12,24,36,48,50],
    'year':[2023,2023,2023,2023,2023]
})
```

my desired output is to have a new column named "weekDate" which will pull the date of the first Monday of the specific week in a "yyyy-MM-dd" format:

E.g. for Week: 12, Year: 2023 ====> "2023-03-20" (which is the first Monday of week 12 in 2023)

Many thanks in advance,

Answer (score 1):

To convert week numbers to dates, you can use the `datetime` module with the `pandas` library.

```
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime, timedelta


df = pd.DataFrame({
    'weeknum':[12,24,36,48,50],
    'year':[2023,2023,2023,2023,2023]
})

# Function to get the date of the first Monday of a given week and year
def get_first_monday(year, week):
    date_str = f'{year}-W{week}'
    date_obj = datetime.strptime(date_str + '-1', "%Y-W%W-%w")
    return date_obj.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')

# Apply the function to create the 'weekDate' column
df['weekDate'] = df.apply(lambda row: get_first_monday(row['year'], row['weeknum']), axis=1)

print(df)
```

Output

```
   weeknum  year    weekDate
0       12  2023  2023-03-20
1       24  2023  2023-06-12
2       36  2023  2023-09-04
3       48  2023  2023-11-27
4       50  2023  2023-12-11
```

Comment: Thanks @codester_09! Just one thing: date_obj = datetime.strptime(date_str + '-1', "%Y-W%W-%w") needs to be : date_obj = datetime.datetime.strptime(date_str + '-1', "%Y-W%W-%w")

Comment: @AlexandraMorel-Fonteray nah you are wrong here, because I have imported the datetime from the datetime library if you see the import statement. `from datetime import datetime, timedelta`. But if you have just import like this `import datetime`, then you have to use it like this  `datetime.datetime.strptime...`.

Answer (score 0):

You can concatenate the columns and use [`to_datetime`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html) with the `'%Y-%W-%w'` format (more info [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior)):

```
df['weekDate'] = pd.to_datetime(
               df['year'].astype(str)+'-'+df['weeknum'].astype(str)+'-1',
               format='%Y-%W-%w')            #                        ^
                                             #          1 is for Monday
# or                                         #                   |
df['weekDate'] = pd.to_datetime(             #                   v
               df['year'].astype(str)+df['weeknum'].astype(str)+'1',
               format='%Y%W%w')
```

Output:

```
   weeknum  year   weekDate
0       12  2023 2023-03-20
1       24  2023 2023-06-12
2       36  2023 2023-09-04
3       48  2023 2023-11-27
4       50  2023 2023-12-11
```